# Use integral comparison to determine if the integral converges or diverges.

Tags: calculus

[image]

For this problem I tried to compare to 1/(t^(4/3)). This integral converges. Does that mean that the original integral also converges? Lets call the simpler integral that I choose, g(t), and the original integral f(t). So I know that if g(t) is bigger than f(t), and g(t) converges, then so does f(t). However, I am having trouble deciding if the g(t) I chose is really larger than f(t) or not. If what I have chosen does not work, do you have any suggestion for what may work?

Comment: The integral you have compared actually diverges. So it means that the original one diverges too.

Comment: Actually @AjmalW for integrals from 1 to infinity of the form 1/x^p, these converge for p>1 and diverge for p</=1 so since in my case, t^(4/3), 4/3 > 1, it should converge shouldn't it?

Comment: You are right. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of comparing this with $t^{-4/3}$ is correct and in fact the integral in your question converges. Nonetheless to be precise this is more an asymptotic estimate than a comparison, since your integral is actually bigger.

What you can do is proving that for some $T$, when $t \ge T$ we have $t^4 - t^3 - 50 \ge t^{3 + 1/2}$. Once you have this you can say that

$$\int_T^{\infty}\frac{1}{(t^4 - t^3 - 50)^{1/3}} \le \int_T^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^{1 + 1/6}} < \infty.$$

I hope that this helps :)

EDIT: 3 is not a problem for us since 3^4 - 3^3 - 50 = 4 > 0

Comment: Okay, so t^(−4/3) is for sure larger than 1/(t^4-t^3-50)^(1/3)? I guess I'm mostly confused about how you can be sure of this inequality

Comment: if you raise both to the power 3 it is easy to compare them and notice that, yes, it is larger :)

Comment: No problem, I glad I could help!